# Android. How to interrupt drag?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am using this code to create drag and drop:

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");

        GlobalTouchX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
        GlobalTouchY = (int) motionEvent.getY();

        shadowBuilder = new MyDragShadowBuilder(view);       

        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, null, 0);

        CurrentDragImage = (ImageView)view;
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return true;
      } else {
      return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I interrupt drag method without waiting drop, or can I call drop event programmatically? I tried many ways, but no luck. For example, it will be great if I can interrupt it here:

```
MainRelative.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {                  
  public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

  int action = event.getAction();

  switch (event.getAction()) {

  case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:    

        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        //HERE I WANT TO INTERRUPT DRAG EVENT ON SOME CONDITION
        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

       break;

  case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

       MyOnDrop(v, event, true);                  

       break;
  }

return true;}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of intercepting the motion would be to override onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) method in the ViewGroup class, This method is called if you are dragging on to the View, So if you need to intercept you will have to place the logic in this method.

For example if you want to use the  FrameLayout to hold your child views. Then you will have to create a new class extending this FrameLayout Class and override the onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) method:

```
class NewFrameLayout extends FrameLayout{


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

     ///Place your logic here to intercept the dragging event


        /*
         * This method JUST determines whether we want to intercept the motion.
         * If we return true, onMotionEvent will be called and we do the actual
         * work here.
         */

        /*
        * Shortcut the most recurring case: the user is in the dragging
        * state and he is moving his finger.  We want to intercept this
        * motion.
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Big thanks! I have all design in xml file, the parent element in it - RelativeLayout. So if use the way you offer I need to create this Parent RelativeLayout programmatically, and use onInterceptTouchEvent. So I need create all Views programmatically also, correct? No way to use xml file for design? Maybe there is way to override onInterceptTouchEvent for existing RelativeLayout?

Comment: What you can do is create the custom RelativeLayout and then use that in the xml. For example if RelativeLayoutNew is the new class then it will simply replace the RelativeLayout in the xml file. I hope it makes sense.